# Form won't calculate totals

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I am having trouble on the Work Orders Form to get the SubTotal to calculate correctly.

**EDIT:** I think that maybe my relationships got messed up or deleted and caused the form to "break" because it was working correctly about a week ago. I am just not completely sure and don't want to risk messing things up further.

The problem is occurring with the Work Order Form and the SubTotal field.

If you look at the Client Tina Rich and run the Work Order, everything works, but not with the other clients.  The database in its entirety, is posted here: REMOVED... [Problem Solved]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:  I updated my SubTotal Control Source to omit non-zeros or nulls:

```
=Nz(DLookUp("[Services Total]","[Services Total]","[WOrderID] = '" & [txtWOrderID] & "'"),0)+Nz(DLookUp("[Parts Total]","[Parts Total]","[WOrderID] = '" & [txtWOrderID] & "'"),0)
```

Simple problem that broke my whole database...

Answer (score 0):

You put the wrong parameter on your subform Column.[Total]
From your form you put Total as summary of [txtSubTotal]+[txtSalesTax]+[txtOnSiteTotal]+[txtDiscount] but I cannot find any text field named txtSubTotal, txtSalesTax, and the rest of that.

If the control come from another subform that is loaded into your mainform.You need to put the [Forms]![parent_form_name]![Children_form_name]![Form] before you refer to the control.

```
E.g : =[Forms]![Main Menu]![Main Menu SubForm 2].[Form]![lblSystemID]
```

Comment: I know that those are using the wrong parameters... that is a whole other issue I am currently working on.

What I am talking about relates to the Work Order form and the SubTotal on that screen.  If you are testing the database:
1. Open Main Menu form
2. Select Tina Rich from the Contact Dropdowm and click Details.
3. Work Order screen is displayed with correct totals.

However if you select any other Contact $0.00 shows up for all totals and doesn't calculate from the Work Order Services / Parts SubForms.